# Atualizar registro cinco minutos após inserção

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:

**tb_simulacao:**

```
id(INT) | codigo(VARCHAR) | flag_valido(INT) | data_hora(DATETIME) | valor(DEC)
```

Eu gostaria que cinco minutos depois que o registro fosse inserido o banco automaticamente mudasse o valor de `flag_valido` para 1. Como eu poderia fazer isso? Eu pesquisei em alguns tópicos mas não achei nada que pudesse resolver meu problema.

Comment: Pesquise por EVENT

Comment: Nao seria o caso de, na hora que for dar o select no registro, comparar a data de inserção com a data atual, e se maior que 5 min, retorna como válido

Answer (score 0):

Ative event_schedule no seu arquivo my.ini
e crie um evento para trocar o status

```
CREATE EVENT evt_change_status ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE DO 
UPDATE nome_tabela
SET flag_valido = 1
WHERE flag_valido = 0 
AND data_hora <= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```